# Plotly by Akevelon boxplot does not give the same result as boxplot in r

Tags: r, plotly, boxplot, plotly.js

I think I have found a possible bug in Plotly by Akevelon of Power bi. The thing is that I have made a boxplot in power bi using the component I mentioned above and I get very different metrics than if I do it with rstudio using the plotly package.

The boxplot I tried to make contains on the x=type and y=publication axis of the following dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aneesayoub/world-universities-ranking-2022?resource=download

This are the results I get by using plotly on power bi

[image]

This are the results I get by using plotly on Rstudio

[image]

The code I used in R is the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
pl=ggplot(my_data,aes(x=type,y=publication))+geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
ggplotly(pl)
```

Any idea of what is the problem?

I tried by using Python and I get the same results as R boxplot

Comment: can we please have a [mcve]? (i.e., what is `my_data` ?)

Comment: Hi @BenBolker my_data is the dataset downloaded from the link of the post

Comment: I think that maybe it's something elated to the dimension of the dataset. I have made a small test with 7 rows and it seems to do it well, but when there are many rows the results are very different.

Comment: In one of your images, the min is larger than the max. It sounds like the data needs to be cleaned.

Comment: When I run the data in R, after I change publication into an integer field, I get the values in your first image (the one you attributed to PowerBI). You'll have to start by inspecting what you expect. If you tell R or Python it's a word, it doesn't matter if it has numbers in it. You can use `gsub(",", "", publication)` and `as.integer()` to clean this data in R.

Comment: @Kat I've tried with another kaggle dataset and I don't get the same results in Power BI as R...

Comment: Did you clean the data? When imported the field `publication` is not a number field; it's a character field because there is a comma. You have to remove the comma and make it a number field...i.e., clean the data or inspect what you expect. Programming languages have advanced significantly over time, but they still can't read your mind. You can use a box plot to look at the centrality strings apparently. That's what is happening in this question's image of the boxplot from R.

Comment: Correct. I have performed data processing tasks and nothing. If you have obtained similar results in R i power bi using Plotly by akvelon can you post your results please, and the process you have performed?

Comment: @Kat I have managed to get it to work as you have told me, however, I think I have detected that when negative data and zeros are available it no longer does well. That is, the results in R or Python and Plotly by Akvelon do not match.

Comment: As long as the numbers are numbers, it doesn't matter if they're zero or negative. However, when you take text from anywhere there can be encoding issues. For example, you need a dash or hyphen for negative numbers. Many word processors, for example, will convert a dash to an endash. R and Python won't interpret an endash or emdash as a dash. - – — <- see the difference? That a dash, endash and emdash.